# Joomla 3.0 Component - Adding field input to JForm using JInput

Tags: database, joomla, upload, joomla3.0, jform

I've added a field in my admin view to upload a file. The upload part is working fine but the form doesn't add the file's name to the database on saving.  I've seen a similar problem here on stack overflow that has been answered but they are using JRequest::setVar which is now deprecated: [How to Save Uploaded File's Name on Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927464/how-to-save-uploaded-files-name-on-database?rq=1)

I need to add to the "jform" array but when I use: $jinput->set('jform',array('foo' => 'bar'));
it overwrites the existing 'jform' array that contains the other data entered in the form:

```
JInput Object (
    [data:protected] => Array (
        [jform] => Array (
            [foo] => bar
            ...
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to add to the jform array and not overwrite it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I feel a little foolish - I've solved my own question!

What I did was to get all the other jform data with: `$jinput->get('jform', NULL, NULL);` and then used `array_merge` to add the other array.

I then used: `$jinput->post->set('jform',$mergedArray);`  to put the array back into the POST.

Hope this helps someone